# [Drupal 7]HTML Tags Visible in content edit section

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

Ive just followed a guide in a drupal book to create a custom compund field.
When it comes to editing content with this field included i notice html tags defined in the custom field's module are visible.

The code:
[image]

The output
[image]

Can anyone help me with reasons as to why these html tags are being output as plain text, rather than creating the divs specified.

Thanks

Comment: But...you're specifically using the `&lt;` HTML entity, so that's what gets written to the page. If you wanted them to be actual elements, shouldn't you replace those with just `<`? (I'm a little confused, not sure if I'm missing something.)

Comment: easy as that mate. Thanks for the help. Cant believe i didnt think fo that

Answer (score -1):

Replace the "amplt;" with "<" . It will work.